# Extract multiple first and last names from a string which contains 2 patterns

Tags: arrays, excel, string, google-sheets, worksheet-function

I have racked my brain trying to work out a formula that (at its worst) takes a string like this in a single cell:

```
GARY ROBERT WARD; KEITH MALCOLM TERRILL & CAMILLA MARGARET WEDGWOOD SWAN; CAMILLA ELIZABETH SWAN-WARD
```

To something that would concatenate the full unique names of each person separated by a ";" or any anchor really:

```
GARY ROBERT WARD; KEITH MALCOLM TERRILL SWAN; CAMILLA MARGARET WEDGWOOD SWAN; CAMILLA ELIZABETH SWAN-WARD
```

Ive done every text to column, split, mid, search, google sheet, regex method I can find but no dice.

Please help :(

Thanks!

Tiana

Comment: Have you tried find(), get the position of the first ; and use that with left to get the first complete name - then use mid() and fund() again but add 1 to the result and feed that into the start-num....

Comment: No the first pattern which contains the "&" would be something like:

{firstname1 firstmiddlename2 firstmiddlename3 & secondname1 secondmiddlename2 LastNameForAllFirstNamesWithinSubstring}

Comment: @SolarMike - sometimes the cell never contains a ";" it could just be:

`SHANE WILLIAM & JULIEANN MARGARET TAYLOR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "&([^;]+)\b([^;]+)", "$2;$1$2")
```

https://regex101.com/r/i0Ki9y

Comment: @I'-'I `+` is greedy so it matches as much as possible. If you notice there is actually nothing in the expression that detects words (except the word boundary `\b`) .. it just matches between `&` and `;`

Comment: @I'-'I maybe modifying the linked regex101 expression can help. They are both greedy, but the first one has precedence, and the second one matches as much as it can after the first one. For example, without the `\b` the second group matches only the last character, but with it it has to match at least one character after a word boundary. If there is for example space before the `;`, it will match only that space.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you pointed out the semi-colon I have gone with that:

[image]

Both work but I left the last one for you - hint use right() and find()

You can change the anchors...

Comment: What did I do wrong in my life to not be able to get this?!

  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGUWx.png">)

Thank you - youve taught me alot about how those functions can be used better! I obviously have some way to go :P

Comment: p.s https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE9iR.png


also have a lot to learn about how to format correctly I give up